# Is there any way to make a noticeboard in shiny dashboard?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to make shiny dashboard. I want to include a bulletin board on my dashboard.
Is there any way to make a noticeboard in my shiny dashboard?

noticeboard like this.
http://oia.snu.ac.kr/page/bo_notice.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
Please show some effort by editing your question and explain what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

This "bulletin board" looks like table with data:(https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.12.1/tableOutput.html).

1. You need to save data which you want to display in some database first.
2. Then connect this db to shiny app. 
   https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/overview.html
3. And then read data from db and show it in table: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html